# What do pulsating gold quality stars mean?

Tags: stardew-valley

If you look closely at the GIF (zoom in if needed), on the top right side of my inventory, there are two Summer Spangle flowers that are of gold quality.  But the gold stars are pulsating.  I've also seen this on some poppy flowers of gold quality.

The Wiki doesn't seem to note this anywhere.  When I harvested the spangles, I also received some silver quality ones, but those aren't pulsating like these ones.  What does it mean?

[image: Stardew Valley inventory showing two harvested spangles with pulsating gold stars]

This isn't the case with all items.  Here is another GIF with a mixture of foraged and harvested items — all of which are gold quality.  Again, only the spangles are pulsating.

[image: Stardew Valley inventory showing multiple gold-star items, but only the gold stars on the two spangles are pulsating]

Comment: Is it not just to highlight the fact that they're gold?

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox I don't think so.  See my edit with the new GIF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because gold is the highest quality those flowers can reach. Any item at the maximum quality possible will have its star pulsate. For some items that's iridium level, but for some they can't go above gold.

(Source: reddit threads on the matter.)

Comment: Why isn't the corn's star pulsating then? [Based upon the Wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Corn#Artisan_Goods) the highest quality that corn can be is also gold.  Could it be because you can make an iridium level juice out of it?  Could you also link those Reddits?

Comment: Possibly, or the wiki could just be wrong. It's been wrong before in regards to a question I had about fishing. (Or the Reddit threads could be wrong!) Hopefully someone can provide some better details.

Comment: This is all true.  I'd like to do some testing for myself but I've yet to obtain any iridium quality items to do this with.  I'm not sure how one can obtain an iridium quality juice if the highest quality for vegetables appears to be gold.  Is it random? I suppose that's another question worth asking if it hasn't already been.

Comment: I'm going to assume that this is the case.  I've got some iridium quality items that do this as well now (the highest quality possible).  It appears flowers (like poppy and summer spangles) max out at gold quality, while things like truffle or milk max out at iridium.  In both of these cases, the stars pulsate.  It also seems foraged items like plums and sweet peas pulse at iridium quality as well.  It appears that crops don't do this in general since iridium quality crops aren't possible from what I can tell, and the gold stars just don't pulsate for any of them.